# Convert IP address from sockaddr_in6 to in_addr

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

Conversion below works fine, but how to deal when I have IPV6?

```
sockaddr foo;
in_addr_t ip_address = ((sockaddr_in)foo).sin_addr.s_addr;
```

Code below fails :

```
sockaddr foo;
in_addr_t ip_address = ((sockaddr_in6)foo).sin6_addr.s_addr;

Error   1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'IN6_ADDR' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Where is code that converts `sockaddr_in` to `in_addr` ?

Comment: IPv6 and IPv4 addresses cannot be converted in this way. Do you want a IPv4 address, that is presented in IPv6 format?

Comment: You may want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157151/isnt-struct-sockadr-in-supposed-to-work-for-both-ipv4-and-ipv6).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no way. IPv6 address can't be converted to `struct in_addr`, unless a corner case happens when it's IPv4-mapped address.

IPv6 host address needs 16 bytes to store and this is covered with `struct in6_addr` in the same headers, for the host part. But, moreover, IPv6 address contains also *scope* in addition to host which may be critical for, e.g., link-local addresses. So, simply using host part isn't enough.

You should read general manuals for programming dual-stack or IPv6-only applications. Particularly, `struct sockaddr_storage` as a common storage for both addresses, and `getaddrinfo` function which does resolving of name (either numeric-only or NETDB).